# ¿MessageBox.Show en modal frente a Form con TopMost = True?

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un form con la propiedad **TopMost = True** que hace que siempre esté por encima de todo, creí que los dialog que generara quedarían por encima de él, ya que se supone que heredan el modal del form principal, pero no lo hace, lo monta siempre atrás

Uso el código normal para llamar un MessageBox

```
MessageBox.Show("Recuerda que debes usar el mismo dedo en todos los intentos." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intenta nuevamente la captura.", "¡ERROR! - Huella Inconsistente", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
```

[image: Propiedad TopMost]

> Propiedad TopMost
>
> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost) forms even if it is not the active or foreground form.

[image: Con ésta propiedad los dialog no se generan por encima del formulario sino se generan siempre atrás de este]

> Con ésta propiedad los dialog no se generan por encima del formulario
>   sino se generan siempre atrás de este

¿Hay una manera de hacer que los diálogos queden encima del form o una forma de que el form quede por encima de todo pero sin opacar los dialog que él mismo genere?

Al parecer un proceso tipo hilo hace que se trunque todo dado que genera algunos dialogs como si fueran de otro form aparte, por eso se generan atrás de este formulario, esto me pasaba por ejemplo al intentar actualizar un label, para eso usaba el siguiente código

```
Delegate Sub AddItemCallBack(ByVal Item As String) 

Protected Sub UpdateCalidad(ByVal calidad As String)
    If Me.LEstadoHuella.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New AddItemCallBack(AddressOf UpdateCalidad)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {calidad})
    Else
        LEstadoHuella.Visible = True
        LEstadoHuella.Text = calidad
    End If
End Sub
```

Sin eso me arroja este error:

> Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control
>   'LEstadoHuella' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó."

---

Este es el método donde llamo el mensaje, ese proceso es del hilo que hace la validación de una huella capturada:

```
Protected Sub Process(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
        DibujarMapa(Sample)

        Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Enrollment)

        ' Se verifica que la calidad haya sido buena para continuar
        If (Not caracteristicas Is Nothing) Then
            Try
                Enroller.AddFeatures(caracteristicas) 'Se agregan las caracteristicas capturadas al template
            Catch ex As Exception
                UpdateCalidad("Huella no coincide o es de mala calidad")
                MessageBox.Show("Recuerda que debes usar el mismo dedo en todos los intentos." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intenta nuevamente la captura.", "¡ERROR! - Huella Inconsistente", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                PictureHuella.Image = Nothing
                Enroller.Clear()
                StopCapture()
                RaiseEvent OnTemplate(Nothing)
                StartCapture()
            Finally
                UpdateStatus()
                'Verificamos si se creó el template
                Select Case Enroller.TemplateStatus

                    Case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Ready    ' Si fue correcto, y se detiene la captura
                        RaiseEvent OnTemplate(Enroller.Template)
                        StopCapture()
                    Case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Failed   ' Fallo el proceso de captura y se reinicia la captura nuevamente
                        Enroller.Clear()
                        StopCapture()
                        RaiseEvent OnTemplate(Nothing)
                        StartCapture()
                End Select
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Pero el problema creo que recae en que se genera en un hilo, entonces lo genera fuera del form principal y quedan sueltos los dos, ¿cómo devolverá el foco al form principal y que genere el dialog en lugar de generarlo heredando al hilo?

---

ENCONTRÉ LA SOLUCIÓN

Hice algo sencillo, creé un textbox invisible y realicé el mismo proceso para verificar que ya habia volvido el hilo al formulario principal, entonces al verificar esto, hice un metodo que se encargaba de generar un mensaje emergente, lo hice con parametros para poderlo usar siempre, con cualquier tipo de dialog que se quiera enviar

> Código con Solución

```
Delegate Sub AddMessageCallBack(ByVal Mensaje As String, ByVal Titulo As String, ByVal Opcion As Integer) 'Delegado que será el que llame nuevamente la opción de Mensajes Emergentes

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Genera de Manera sincrona el mensaje emergente
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="mensaje"></param>
    ''' <param name="titulo"></param>
    ''' <param name="tipo"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Protected Sub SendMensaje(ByVal mensaje As String, ByVal titulo As String, ByVal tipo As Integer)
        If Me.TXTMensajes.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New AddMessageCallBack(AddressOf SendMensaje)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {mensaje, titulo, tipo})
        Else
            Select Case tipo
                Case 1 'Error
                    MessageBox.Show(mensaje, titulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Case 2 'Exclamation
                    MessageBox.Show(mensaje, titulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Case 3 'Information
                    MessageBox.Show(mensaje, titulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End Select

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu problema. ¿Puedes compartir un [mcve] por favor?

Comment: Escribir código funcional acá para visual creo que no es posible, espero que con la imágenes agregadas sea más entendible...

Comment: Tristemente, no es suficiente. Realmente se necesita un [mcve]. No tiene porqué ser tu programa tal cual. Solo algo bien minimalista (pero completo), lo suficiente para reproducir tu problema. Porque cuando yo hago la prueba, tengo un form marcado con `TopMost = True`, y a partir de ese forumulario hago el `MessageBox.Show()` idéntico al tuyo, y en mi prueba, el diálogo se presenta encima del formulario, no detrás. De modo que tengo que suponer que hay algo diferente en la forma como tu lo haces.

Comment: Creo que debe ser porque estoy usando un proceso de hilo para saber el estado del lector de huellas, entonces genera el dialog como si fuera de otro form, me dí cuenta porque puedo seleccionar el dialog y tambien el form como si estos fueran independientes...

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido lo que dices. Pero es por eso mismo que siempre insisto en un [mcve]. Así como está la pregunta ahora, los detalles importantes que causan tu problema no los tenemos, de modo que no se puede contestar la pregunta.

Comment: Acabe de agregar uno de los métodos que utilizó para solucionarlo al momento de actualizar labels, no sé si eso pueda ayudar...

Comment: Hola Fabian. No había visto tu última edición, pero aun así, espero que concuerdes que eso en realidad no es un [mcve]. Esos son fragmentos de código incompletos y sin contexto que no puedo simplemente copiar y correr de mi lado para reproducir tu problema.  No digo que sea imposible usar esta información para contestar la pregunta, pero requiere mucho mas esfuerzo de mi parte porque ahora me toca a mi armar los pedazos que faltan. Esa no debería ser mi responsabilidad, sino la tuya. El enlace contiene todos los principios necesarios para incluir el código necesario.

Comment: Lo que sucede no es que no quiera colocar mi código, es que uso las lecturas de un lector biometrico, entonces a menos que lo tengas también podrás probar por completo el código, lo que hacen es generar procesos de hilo que están siempre atentos a los cambios que el lector genere, y los dialog los llamo desde estos subprocesos que generan, de ahí parece que los toma de otro form, no sé es cómo sacarlos para que vuelvan salgan del hilo y vuelvan al form principal y se generen allí, uno de los dialog lo saque con timer a medio segundo y este funciona

Comment: Podria ser una rutina que genere cualquier mensaje pasado el medio segundo, pero no sabria cómo generarlo para enviarle al proceso del timer tambien los parametros del mensaje, el titulo y el tipo de alerta que generaria

Comment: Hice una solución no muy común pero funcional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice algo sencillo, creé un textbox invisible y realicé el mismo proceso para verificar que ya habia volvido el hilo al formulario principal, entonces al verificar esto, hice un metodo que se encargaba de generar un mensaje emergente, lo hice con parámetros para poderlo usar siempre, con cualquier tipo de dialog que se quiera enviar

> Código con Solución

```
Delegate Sub AddMessageCallBack(ByVal Mensaje As String, ByVal Titulo As String, ByVal Opcion As Integer) 'Delegado que será el que llame nuevamente la opción de Mensajes Emergentes

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Genera de Manera sincrona el mensaje emergente
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="mensaje"></param>
    ''' <param name="titulo"></param>
    ''' <param name="tipo"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Protected Sub SendMensaje(ByVal mensaje As String, ByVal titulo As String, ByVal tipo As Integer)
        If Me.TXTMensajes.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New AddMessageCallBack(AddressOf SendMensaje)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {mensaje, titulo, tipo})
        Else
            Select Case tipo
                Case 1 'Error
                    MessageBox.Show(mensaje, titulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Case 2 'Exclamation
                    MessageBox.Show(mensaje, titulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Case 3 'Information
                    MessageBox.Show(mensaje, titulo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End Select

        End If
    End Sub
```